# Why can't I deduce one of the class template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction

I have some code here

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size, typename funcType>
struct foo
{
public:

    foo(const funcType& func) : m_func(func) {}
    ~foo() {}
    
    void m_call() { m_func(); }

private:
    const funcType& m_func;

    T x[size];
};

void printString() { std::cout << "some string\n"; }
```

I can create an object

```
foo<int, 3, void(*)()> someObject(printString);
```

or

```
foo<int, 3, decltype(printString)> someObject(printString);
```

but when I try to do this:

```
foo<int, 3> someObject(printString);
```

I get this error on g++ 10.2

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 3)
 foo<int, 3> someObject(printString);
           ^
note: provided for 'template<class T, long unsigned int size, class funcType> struct foo'
 struct foo
```

Why cant I do this? Doesn't the compiler know what type `printString` is?

And if I change the `foo` to

```
template<typename funcType>
struct foo
{
public:

    foo(const funcType& func) : m_func(func) {}
    ~foo() {}
    
    void m_call() { m_func(); }

private:
    const funcType& m_func;
};
```

I can create it normally

```
foo someObject(printString);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction):

> Class template argument deduction is only performed if no template
> argument list is present. If a template argument list is specified,
> deduction does not take place.

which your last experiment confirms. To deduce `funcType` you also need to provide other templated types in constructor to not provide any template argument list.

You can bind other templates with constructor for example using this construct:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, std::size_t size, typename funcType>
struct foo
{
public:
    foo(T (&arr)[size], const funcType& func) : m_func(func) {}
    ~foo() {}

    void m_call() { m_func(); }

private:
    const funcType& m_func;
    T x[size]{};
};

void printString() { std::cout << "some string\n"; }


void test() {
    foo someObject("test", printString);

}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nbGxGs)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. CTAD requires all the template parameters to be deduced which is not possible for the first 2 parameters of the class.

Comment: Well, the question is "Why can't I deduce one of the class template arguments?", answer is you can't because you provide partial information, either provide by hand all, or none to even start deducing. Which I agree will fail, as constructor only creates guide for last template argument.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right, this does address the question. I misread it, since you hadn't shown an alternative, but that's perfectly fine.

Comment: It’s worth saying *why* this restriction exists, which is backward compatibility with class templates with default template arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use template function to create the object and to deduct missing template arguments from function call. Something like this.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size, typename FunctionT>
foo<T, Size, FunctionT> create_foo(const FunctionT &func) {
    return foo<T, Size, FunctionT>(func);
} 

auto foo_obj = create_foo<int, 3>(printString);
```